# Variables with decimals on Javascript calculations

Tags: javascript, function

I' ve made this simple form which calculates the BMI from Height and Weight Variables. It works when i insert integers to Height and Weight variables respectively, but unfortunately it doesn't work the way it should when i insert decimal numbers.

Any thoughts on fixing this issue?

```js
function Calculate() {
  var manWeight = document.getElementById('manWeight').value;
  var manHeight = document.getElementById('manHeight').value;

  document.getElementById('manBMI').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('manWeight').value) / Math.pow(parseInt(document.getElementById('manHeight').value), 2);
  
}
```

```html
<label for="manWeight">Weight: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="manWeight" size="35" id="manWeight" required autocomplete="off">
  <br>

<label for="manHeight">Height: *</label>
  <input type="text" name="manHeight" size="35" id="manHeight" required autocomplete="off"> <br>

<label for="manBMI">BMI:</label>
  <input type="text" name="manBMI" size="35" id="manBMI" required disabled autocomplete="off">

<button type="button" id="calculator" name="calculator" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Cerbrus can you please explain me how am i supposed to know that the root of my problem could be found in that article? And you also downvote a fair answer. Stack Overflow is built to make our lives simpler not more complex, especially for us who are self taught developers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `parseInt(value)` when calculating the final values. parseInt will round down any floats that you can pass in.

You can instead use `Number(value)`. Which will parse floats. But this will return NaN if you input invalid characters.

You can use the input type of `Number` in limit the inputs to valid numbers. (on supported browsers)

```js
function Calculate() {
  var manWeight = document.getElementById('manWeight').value;
  var manHeight = document.getElementById('manHeight').value;

  document.getElementById('manBMI').value = Number(document.getElementById('manWeight').value) / Math.pow(Number(document.getElementById('manHeight').value), 2);
  
}
```

```html
<label for="manWeight">Weight: *</label>
  <input type="number" name="manWeight" size="35" id="manWeight" required autocomplete="off">
  <br>

<label for="manHeight">Height: *</label>
  <input type="number" name="manHeight" size="35" id="manHeight" required autocomplete="off"> <br>

<label for="manBMI">BMI:</label>
  <input type="text" name="manBMI" size="35" id="manBMI" required disabled autocomplete="off">

<button type="button" id="calculator" name="calculator" onclick="Calculate();">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @nipuna777 ! I used the first answer of yours which worked perfectly, i'm not the one who downvoted ...